# Summing up list members step by step

Tags: r, sum, cumulative-sum

I've got a very simple problem but I was unable to find a simple solution in R because I was used to solve such problems by iterating through an incrementing for-loop in other languages.

Let's say I've got a random distributed numeric list like:

```
rand.list <- list(4,3,3,2,5)
```

I'd like to change this random distributed pattern into a constantly rising pattern so the result would look like:

```
[4,7,10,12,17]
```

Comment: Man that was quick. Your solution works. Could you post that as an answer so I could mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came to me first to do `cumsum(unlist(rand.list))`, where `unlist` collapses the list into  a plain vector. However, my lucky try shows that `cumsum(rand.list)` also works.

It is not that clear to me how this work, as the source code of `cumsum` calls `.Primitive`, an internal S3 method dispatcher which is not easy to further investigate. But I make another complementary experiment as follow:

```
x <- list(1:2,3:4,5:6)
cumsum(x)  ## does not work

x <- list(c(1,2), c(3,4), c(5,6))
cumsum(x)  ## does not work
```

In this case, we have to do `cumsum(unlist(x))`.

Comment: Your solution works equally well to the Reduce function but this function seems to be specially addressed for my problem so I mark it as solution.

Comment: I'm still kinda a newb when it comes to R so I apologize. With C-level evaluation you mean that cumsum is using vectorization techniques like those apply functions for iterating lists and is therefore faster?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Reduce` with the `accumulate` parameter set to `TRUE`:

```
Reduce("+",rand.list, accumulate = T)
```

I hope this helps.